# How can we write data in CSV from Beanshell

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

While executing below code in eclipse its working but not working in bean shell   ?  it displaying error near   writer.write(data);

So please help me out how can we pass string array from beanshell to csv

```
 import java.io.*;
        import java.io.FileWriter;
        import java.io.BufferedWriter;
        import java.util.List;
        int i;
            File file = new File("/home/sarvesh/Desktop/sgi/10");
        int filecount =  file.list().length;
        File[] files = file.listFiles();

        String[] imageString = new String[filecount];

            for ( i =0;i<filecount;i++) {
               File f = new File(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);   

               byte [] byteArray = new byte[(int) f.length()];
               fis.read(byteArray);
                imageString[i] = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArray);

                    //vars.put("imagData",imageString[i]);

           FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/home/sarvesh/Desktop/sgi/base64_csv.csv"); 

                  //    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>(); 
                    ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
                data.add(new String[] {imageString[i] });
                    **writer.write(data);**
                    // writer.write(imageString[i]);
                    // writer.close();

            System.out.println("***********************************************");
    System.out.println("Base 64 conversion of  Image  : " + i + " ::" + imageString[i]);
            System.out.println("File Path     :                  " + f.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("***********************************************");

                    }
```

Comment: What is the displayed error?

Comment: 2020-06-03 18:31:34,172 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``        import java.io.*;         import java.io.FileWriter;         import java . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Method write( java.util.ArrayList ) not found in class'java.io.FileWriter'

Comment: some time it print only last index data

Answer (score 1):

1. Beanshell is not Java, it doesn't support [diamond operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Diamond_operator) therefore you need to change this line:

   ```
   List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
   ```

   to this one:

   ```
   List data = new ArrayList();
   ```
2. [Starting from JMeter 3.1 you should rather be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting
3. Your approach will work given you run your test with 1 thread (virtual user), if there will be more users - you'll run into the [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) resulting into file corruption/data loss so if you need to write some specific data into some specific file it's better to go for the [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/). Alternatively you can use [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller) but it will slow down your test